# Is it possible to copy and past an Element in Enterprise Architect by using the Java API?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to create diagrams through the Enterprise Architect Java API. Since we got a template for our diagrams, the simplest approach would be to copy the element in which the diagram is placed and paste it into the desired place.

I found the method clone() form the package class but I did not find any similar method for the element class or the diagram class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it "manually" by creating a new element or diagram and copying all properties to the new element, but that is quite some work.

Or you could move everything you want to copy into a package and then use `EA.Package.Clone()`. After cloning the package you can move the source elements back to their original location.

Comment: I moved the template (an Element and a composite Diagram) into the Package and then used EA.Package.Clone(). How do I take the Element and the diagram out of the Package now? I tried Package.GetElement.SetParentID() but it occured an Error. Thank you Geert for the great tips!

Comment: Set the ´EA.Element.PackageID` to the package you want to move the element to. The `EA.Element.ParentID` is used to indicate the element that owns (embeds) the element. Also don't forget to save your changes by calling `EA.Element.Update()`

Comment: It worked. Now the last step i want to do is to add an existing Package as an element to the diagram. I tried Diagram.GetDiagramObjects.AddNew() and then DiagramObject.SetElementID but nothing happened. I already added other existing elements to the diagram but with the package it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to set the `EA.DiagramObject.ElementID` tot the `EA.Package.Element.ElementID`